# how do i get rid of the zero that shows up after all my elements in my array are listed?

Tags: java, arrays, drjava

i have to make a program that prints out the elements of an array filled with random numbers backwards but it also prints out a zero after my variables? i think it has something to do with my for-loops but i get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`error any time i try to change them.

**edit:** i also noticed that the first printed element is always zero. i don't really see it as a problem but what could be causing that?

```
import java.util.*;

public class EZD_printBackwards
{
    static int vars[] = new int[10];

    static int backwards()
    { 
        Random rand = new Random();
        int bkwds = vars[0];

        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) 
        {
            vars[a] = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
        }

        for (int x = 10; x > 0; x--)
        {
            System.out.println("Element " + x + " is " + vars[x] );      
        }
        return bkwds;
    }

    public static void main(String Args[])
    {

       int option;
       Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);

       do
       {
           System.out.println(backwards());
           System.out.print("Type 1 to run again. Type 0 to end the program.");
           option = kbReader.nextInt();

           while(option !=1 && option !=0)
           {

               if (option != 1 && option != 0)
               {
                   System.out.print("Please enter 1 to run again or 0 to end the program.");
                   option = kbReader.nextInt();
               }
           }

       }while(option==1);

       System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: `int x = 10; x > 0; x--` is probably your problem. Change 10 to 9; You array indexes goes from 0 to 9. It would be easier to probably use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: You have a lot of stuff going on with your `do while`, `while`, and `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

FIRST => For loop out of bounds

you want to go through 10 elements, therefore your

```
for (int x = 10; x > 0; x--)
```

should be

```
for (int x = 9; x >= 0; x--)
```

0..9 is 10 elements and the same things goes for

```
for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
```

to

```
for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
```

SECOND ==> 0 at the end

That's because you do

```
System.out.println(backwards());
```

instead of

```
backwards();
```

Comment: Your answer does not account for the first element in the array in the second for loop. The condition should be `x >= 0`

Comment: @sparkplug your absoluty right. I even did it on IntelliJ the right way to try it!

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `vars` is size 10. The second for loop starts at index `x = 10` which is greater than the last index of vars because array index starts at zero. To fix the issue, you should use this condition in your for loop:

```
 for (int x = vars.length -1; x >= 0; x--)
 {
  System.out.println("Element " + x + " is " + vars[x] );      
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are returning the value of "bkwds", and you are initializing "bkwds"  with vars[0] , and i guess in java the compiler initialize all the values of an array with  0 , 
in other words your probleme is in `System.out.println(backwards());`

remove it with

```
backwards();
```

and it should work !

> EDIT

your look is out of bound either replace it with this

```
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++)
```

or 
do this

```
        for (int a = 9; a > 0; a--)
```

Answer (score 1):

As arrays are indexed from zero, change to

```
System.out.println("Element " + x + " is " + vars[x-1] );
```

**output**

```
Element 10 is 31
Element 9 is 63
Element 8 is 82
Element 7 is 46
Element 6 is 67
Element 5 is 24
Element 4 is 3
Element 3 is 27
Element 2 is 37
Element 1 is 13
```

**edit**

And change this

```
System.out.println(backwards());
```

to

```
backwards();
```

As the return value of this method is useless and not used, change this method to return void

Comment: you sure that this is the problem ?

Comment: @AhmedBaoun I am never sure of anything

Answer (score 1):

The range of your Array is from 0 up to and including 9. Your for loop, however, is starting from 10 and coming down to index 1. It should start from 9 and comes down to index zero. This, however, does not explain printing random 0! The reason for these zeros is you have an int bkwds which youb set to vars[0] at the beginning of your function. But, since it is not initialized, it will be set to 0 (the default for int) In your main, you call the function in a print statement, which I suppose keeps printing that falsely, useless initialized variable that you return :)